# C# HTML.Actionlink strange behaviour on server

Tags: c#, html.actionlink

If someone can help, I would be very thankful.

I'm using C# in VS 2017 for an ASP.net Application.

In a razor view, I have this code:

```
    <div class="text-center"  >

    <ul class="pagination">
        @for (var i = 1; i <= ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchNumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            if (ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchCurrentPage == @i)
            {
                <li class="active"> @Html.ActionLink(@i.ToString(), "CI_SequenceBlocks_Pager_Form_Handler", new { id = @i, value = ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchString, inInstitutionProgramID = ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() },null)</li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li> @Html.ActionLink(@i.ToString(), "CI_SequenceBlocks_Pager_Form_Handler", "Home", new { id = @i, value = ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchString, inInstitutionProgramID = ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() },null)</li>

            }
        }

    </ul>
</div>
```

}

It works great on my development machine.  The actionlinks never fail.

However, when I publish to the server, I can click on the links 3 or 4 times and they work.  After the 4th time, it is like the variables are forgotten.  When I view the page source the links appear to correct.  It seems to me something on the server is being reset.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is more code:
____________EDIT AFTER THIS LINE__________________
Controller:

```
 public ActionResult CI_SequenceBlocks()
    {
        string strIP = "";
        string strSRCHString = "";
        string strSRCHstringQry = "";
        int intSRCHRequestedPage = 1;
        int intSRCHPageSize = 10;
        if (TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"] == null)
        {
            strIP = "0";
            strSRCHString = "";
        }
        else
        {
            strIP = TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"].ToString();
            strSRCHString = TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_SRCHString"]?.ToString() ?? "";
        };
        ViewData["listInstitutionPrograms"] = new SelectList(MSSQL_CI_Repository.ListInstitutionProgramsForComboBoxes(), "Value", "Text");
        ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"] = strIP;
        ViewData["inSRCHString"] = strSRCHString;
        ViewBag.SRCHString = strSRCHString;
        //ViewBag.InstitutionalProgram = strIP;
        if (strSRCHString == "") { ViewBag.SRCHDescriptor = "NO_SEARCH_TERM"; } else { ViewBag.SRCHDescriptor = strSRCHString?.ToString() ?? "NO_SEARCH_TERM"; }
        if (strSRCHString.Trim() == "")

        {
            strSRCHstringQry = "rttyghujmgdddh";
        }
        else
        {
            strSRCHstringQry = strSRCHString;
        }
        if(TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_RequestedPage"] != null)
        {
            intSRCHRequestedPage = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_RequestedPage"]);
        }
        vm_CI_SequenceBlocksWithSearchMetaData obj = MSSQL_CI_Repository.ListCI_SequenceBlocksByInstitutionalProgramForFullTextSearch(Convert.ToInt32(strIP), strSRCHstringQry,intSRCHPageSize,intSRCHRequestedPage);
        ViewBag.SearchMetaData = obj.SearchMetaData;
        var model = obj.lstSequenceBlocks;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult CI_SequenceBlocks_FullTextSearch(FormCollection form)
    {
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"] = form["HidInstitutionProgram"].ToString();
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_SRCHString"] = form["SRCHString"].ToString();
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_RequestedPage"] = 1;
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("CI_SequenceBlocks");
    }

    public ActionResult CI_SequenceBlocks_Edit_Form_Handler(int id, string value, int inInstitutionProgramID)
    {
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgramID"] = inInstitutionProgramID;
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_SequenceBlockID"] = id;
        if (value == "Edit_SequenceBlock_ID")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CI_SequenceBlock_Edit");
        }
        else if (value == "Maintain_SequenceBlock_ID")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CI_SequenceBlock_Maintain");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"] = inInstitutionProgramID;
            return RedirectToAction("CI_SequenceBlocks");

        }

        }

    public ActionResult CI_SequenceBlocks_Pager_Form_Handler(int id, string value, int inInstitutionProgramID)
    {
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"] = inInstitutionProgramID;
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_SRCHString"] = value;
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_RequestedPage"] = id;
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("CI_SequenceBlocks");
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult CI_SequenceBlocks_ProgramChange(FormCollection form)
    {
        TempData["CI_SequenceBlocks_InstitutionProgram"] = form["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString();
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("CI_SequenceBlocks");
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
  public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

Full Razor Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<UTCI_Manager.Models.vm_CI_SequenceBlock>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CI_SequenceBlocks";
}

<h2>CI_SequenceBlocks</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("CI_SequenceBlocks_ProgramChange", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstitutionProgramID)
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedInstitutionProgram", (SelectList)ViewData["listInstitutionPrograms"], new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("CI_Sequenceblocks_FullTextSearch", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
    if (ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.Hidden("HidInstitutionProgram", ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"]?.ToString() ?? "0")
            @Html.TextBox("SRCHString", ViewData["inSRCHString"].ToString(), new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type='submit' value="Search">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    }
}
        <table class="table table-striped" summary="List of Sequence Blocks">

            <tr>

                @*     <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SequenceBlockID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstitutionProgramID)
            </th>
                *@
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SequenceBlockDescription)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SequenceBlockRequired)
                </th>
                @*     <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Minimum)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Maximum)
            </th>
                *@

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SequenceBlockTimingMethod)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </th>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClerkshipModel)
                </th>

                <th>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("CI_SequenceBlocks_AddSequenceBlock", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
                    {
                        if (ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() != "0")
                        {
                            @Html.Hidden("HidInstitutionalProgram", ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString())
                            <input type="submit" value="Add Sequence Block" class="btn btn-sm" />
                        }
                    }

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SequenceBlockID)

                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.InstitutionProgramID)

                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Minimum)

                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Maximum)


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SequenceBlockDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SequenceBlockRequired)
                    </td>



                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SequenceBlockTimingMethod)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Duration)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClerkshipModel)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CI_SequenceBlocks_Edit_Form_Handler", new { id = item.SequenceBlockID, value = "Edit_SequenceBlock_ID", inInstitutionProgramID = item.InstitutionProgramID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Maintain", "CI_SequenceBlocks_Edit_Form_Handler", new { id = item.SequenceBlockID, value = "Maintain_SequenceBlock_ID", inInstitutionProgramID = item.InstitutionProgramID })


                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    @if (ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() != "0")
    {

        <div class="text-center"  >

            <ul class="pagination">
                @for (var i = 1; i <= ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchNumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    if (ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchCurrentPage == @i)
                    {
                        <li class="active"> @Html.ActionLink(@i.ToString(), "CI_SequenceBlocks_Pager_Form_Handler", new { id = @i, value = ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchString, inInstitutionProgramID = ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() },null)</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li> @Html.ActionLink(@i.ToString(), "CI_SequenceBlocks_Pager_Form_Handler", "Home", new { id = @i, value = ViewBag.SearchMetaData.SearchString, inInstitutionProgramID = ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() },null)</li>

                    }
                }

            </ul>
        </div>
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm("CI_SequenceBlocks_AddSequenceBlock", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
    if (ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden("HidInstitutionProgram", ViewData["SelectedInstitutionProgram"].ToString())
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Add Sequence Block:</td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value="Add Sequence Block" class="btn btn-sm" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

____________NEW UPDATE____________

Found the issue:

I changed RedirectToActionPermanent to RedirectToAction.  No more problems!

Thanks,

James

Comment: Hi James, welcome to SO. In order for us to help you, you need to include more details, such as the rendered HTML, target controller's code and any routes that may be defined. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't know that this would have anything to do but your active link is missing the controller name. There is an overload without it but if anything, it's worth checking for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Also, I don't think the `i` variable needs the `@` sign since it's already inside a code block.

Comment: Thank you JuanR.  I added the controller name but it did not help.